# In Azure DevOps is there provision of any external link to client by which they can only access bugs or selective work items created by them?

Tags: azure-devops, client, project-management, bug-tracking, workitem

Our organization is using Azure DevOps to for project management. Currently, to track work progress, which tasks are pending, which are done, issues raised etc. in project we give full access to clients, such that they can view activities happening in that project. Now as an organization, we want to restrict client from viewing the activities done by our internal team. We don't want them to view bugs created by our QA Team to developers. We only want them to CREATE & VIEW bugs created by them. Is there any provision to give only those rights to the client ?
Can we give rights for external users (clients) to create bugs and view status of bugs created by THEM only & RESTRICT view of bugs/work items created by internal team team members? Please assist.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Is there any provision to give only those rights to the client? Can we give rights for external users (clients) to create bugs and view status of bugs created by THEM only & RESTRICT view of bugs/work items created by internal team members?

You could consider to [add these external users (clients) to be a new team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page), and then set "*View permissions for this node*" permission and "*View work items in this node*" permission for this team to be **Deny** for specific areas, so the team cannot view work items under these areas. See: [Set permissions and access for work tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops) for more details.
[image]

Comment: thanks for response. I did set as per configuration told by you above. But denying the "view workitems in this node / view permission for this node", restricts the client from viewing their own created Workitems too. How to prevent that? Client should have atleast permission to view workitems created by him /her?

Comment: If internal team members create work item under the same area with external clients, Azure DevOps cannot achieve to make external clients can view their created work items but hide others' created work items. The workaround is to set separate area/node for these clients/the new client group, and allow them to create work items under this area/node.

Comment: Hi Charlie, Does my answer help? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.